# How do I add an authorization based on associations in Active Record Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Club, which has many Memberships, and has many Users through Memberships. (Memberships is a joiner table)

I want to write an authorization where a user @current_user (using sessions) can only view a certain club's details if they are a member

I am having trouble doing this in controller. When I render the query "Membership.where(club_id: params[:id])", and try to look for just the users, I get:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "MotherGoose",
            "email": "mg@example.com",
            "password": null
        },
        "club": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Goose's Digest",
            "description": "All genres welcome",
            "admin": {
                "username": "MotherGoose",
                "id": 1
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Because my Membership serializer looks like this:

```
class MembershipSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :club

end
```

Obviously this is really slow to iterate through, but I can't design a serializer for a where query. And I feel like I shouldn't need a serializer to do this -- that's for communicating for frontend. Any tips?

Here's an authorization example that I'm trying to replicate:

```
return render json: { error: "Not authorized" }, status: :unauthorized unless session.include? :user_id
```

Except replace "session.include? :user_id" with a test that determines whether `Membership.where(club_id: params[:id])` includes a user with the id of @current_user

Comment: If I understand, you want to hide some details in the club object only if the user is a member of that club? If so is the club serializer do that currently?

Comment: @urchmaney Yeah I worry I'm not explaining myself -- I want to make something like this:

`return render json: { error: "Not authorized" }, status: :unauthorized unless session.include? :user_id`

but instead of "session.include", it's testing whether "Membership.where(club_id: params[:id])" includes a user with the id of @current_user

Comment: Try `Membership.exists? (club_id: params[:id], user_id: @current_user.id)`

Comment: Your initition is correct - the serializer has absolutely nothing to do with what you're trying to accomplish. Include the models and controller in the question instead. Also have you considered using an authorization layer such as Pundit or CanCanCan?